# Bootstrap Modal - window darkens but no modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, mustache

I have a mustache.js template that contains an `<a>` which targets `myModal` like so:

```
<script id="profile-preview-template" type="text/template"> 
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a style="display:block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <div class="profile-preview">
                <img class="img-responsive img-circle center-block" width="200px" src="{{img_url}}" alt="Photo of {{first_name}} {{last_name}}" />
                <h1>{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</h1>
                <h2 class="text-muted">{{major}}</h2>
                <h3 class="text-muted">Cohort {{cohort}}</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</script>
```

Here is the modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">BluLocker</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-1">
                                <img src="img/portfolio/blulocker1.jpg" alt="BluLocker" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <p>...</p>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When the result is clicked it darkens the screen but no modal is displayed. I am led to believe that the modal is conflicting with something in the javascript because i cannot get a modal to work anywhere on the site directory.

here are my links to javascript:

```
    <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Mousctache.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.1.3/mustache.js"></script>

<!-- Custom JavaScript -->
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

I also have a few inline script tags running JS
I need to get the modal to display upon clicking the `<a>` in the moustache.js template.

FYI here is the full HTML page starting at the `<body>` tag:

```
<body>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">BluLocker</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-1">
                            <img src="img/portfolio/blulocker1.jpg" alt="BluLocker" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <p>...</p>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/EPG.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="apply.html">APPLY</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">RESOURCES <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="calander.html">Calander</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="people.html">People</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">ETC</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">ETC</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">ETC</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('img/slidedeck/ex1.jpg')">
    <div style="background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="site-heading">
                    <h1>NETWORK</h1>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <h2 class="subheading">The most valuable part of EPG is the people.</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header> 
<div class="search-navbar">
    <input type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder=""/>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="profile-results" class="row">

    </div>  
</div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <ul class="list-inline text-center">
                        <li>
                            <a href="" target="_blank">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="" target="_blank">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-youtube fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="copyright text-muted">Copyright &copy; Entrepreneurship for the Public Good 2015</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Then I have a bunch of inline JavaScript and the closing `</body>`:

```
<script id="profile-preview-template" type="text/template"> 
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a style="display:block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <div class="profile-preview">
                <img class="img-responsive img-circle center-block" width="200px" src="{{img_url}}" alt="Photo of {{first_name}} {{last_name}}" />
                <h1>{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</h1>
                <h2 class="text-muted">{{major}}</h2>
                <h3 class="text-muted">Cohort {{cohort}}</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</script>

<script id="modal-template" type="text/template">
<div id="myModal">
    <div class="contianer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img width="300px" src="{{img_url}}" alt="Profile of {{first_name}} {{last_name}}" class=" img-circle img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</h1>
                <h2>{{major}}</h2>
                <h3>{{cohort}}</h3>
                <h4>{{home_town}}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h1>About {{first_name}}</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h3>Status:{{status}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "row">
            <p>{{bio}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>            
    <a href="{{linkedin}}">LinkedIn &rarr;</a>            
</div>

</script>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Mousctache.js -->
<script   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.1.3/mustache.js"></script>

<!-- Custom JavaScript -->
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#search').keyup(function() {
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    $.getJSON('/profiles.json', function(data){
        var result =""
        $.each(data.profiles, function(key, val){

            var fullName = val.first_name + " " + val.last_name
            var cohortNum = val.cohort.toString()
            var cohortName = "cohort " + cohortNum
            if ((val.first_name.search(myExp) != -1) || 
                (val.last_name.search(myExp) != -1) ||
                (val.major.search(myExp) != -1) ||
                (fullName.search(myExp) != -1)||
                (cohortNum.search(myExp) != -1)||
                (cohortName.search(myExp) != -1)
                ){
                    var template = $('#profile-preview-template').html();
                    result += Mustache.render(template, val);       
            }
        });
        $('#profile-results').html(result);
    });
});
</script>

</body>
```

And also FYI here is the custom.js file:

```
$(function(){ 
//Variables
var slideqty = $('#featured .item').length; //get the number of slides in the carousel deck
var wheight = $(window).height(); //get the height of the window
var randSlide = Math.floor(Math.random()*slideqty); //pick a random number from 0-slideqty

//makeIndicators
//Automatically make indicators on the carousel for each slide in the deck
for (var i=0; i < slideqty; i++) {
    var insertText = '<li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="' + i + '"';
    if (i === 0) {
        insertText += ' class="active" ';
    }
    insertText += '></li>';
    $('#featured ol').append(insertText);
}

$('.carousel').carousel({
    pause: false
}); // end of makeIndicator

//fullHeight
// set all elements with class "fullheight" to a height equal to height of viewport on load
$('.fullheight').css('height', wheight);

//resize the "fullheight" elements on screen resize
$(window).resize(function() {
    wheight = $(window).height(); //get the height of the window
    $('.fullheight').css('height', wheight); //set to window tallness
});

//adjust the interval of the carousel
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000 //changes the speed in miliseconds
})

//make images darker
$('.item img').each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="tint"></div>'); //wraps the carousel images with a div of class "tint"
});

//animate the contents of the search bar
var txt = "Search by name, major, or cohort.";
var timeOut;
var txtLen = txt.length;
var char = 0;
$('#search').attr('placeholder', '|');
(function typeIt() {
    var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (200 - 30)) + 30;
    timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        char++;
        var type = txt.substring(0, char);
        $('#search').attr('placeholder', type + '|');
            typeIt();

        if (char == txtLen) {
            $('#search').attr('placeholder', $('#search').attr('placeholder').slice(0, -1)) // remove the '|'
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }

    }, humanize);
}()
);

//shuffle takes an array and shuffles it
function shuffle(o){ //v1.0
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};

//load 20 random profiles
function loadRand(){
    $.getJSON('/profiles.json', function(data){
        rand = ""
        randProfiles = shuffle(data.profiles);
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            var template = $('#profile-preview-template').html();
            rand += Mustache.render(template, randProfiles[i]);
        }
        $('#profile-results').html(rand);
    });
};
loadRand(); //load random profiles on refresh

//if search is empty load 20 random profiles
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    if (searchField == ''){
        loadRand();
    }
});

}); //end of main function
```

Answer (score 0):

Change id of your div from item1 to "myModal" as you are using data-target="#myModal" in your code.

Comment: Turns out I copied the wrong modal to make this post. I fixed it in the post so that "myModal" is the id of the modal. By the way, it still does not work, even with the id matching the data-target attribute value.

Comment: (1). I see that container is incorrectly spelled. its writtern as "contianer" instead of container. (2) Also anchor tag <a> is inside <script> I dont understand why. You can close the <script id="profile-preview-template" type="text/template"> </script> and move  <div class="col-sm-3"> outside.  (3) You can check the fiddle here. I was able to click on the image and get the modal working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/qL7x1sse/2/

Comment: (1). Fixed the spelling. (2). the <div class="col-sm-3"> has to be inside the script tag. It is a javascript template that is used to match .JSON data that I have. The mustache.js library handles that. So my result it dozens of profiles made from JSON data using that template where things like {{first_name}} refer to JSON objects and the object's value is substituted there in the actual HTML.

Comment: I read about moustache.js. I was able to get it working in my local workspace and have also edited jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qL7x1sse/4/  please check. You have not shared all details of your code. where does it fail. Are you able to click on photo or user firstname last name to launch modal window? I dont see where you are using template to paint html content. Also make sure data which you receiving is properly formatted.  I added new js method "painthtml" to use hardcoded data, template and paint html in newly added div "testArea". when you say not working ,define not working in detail.

Comment: The mustache templates work fine, they load up dozens of profiles from my json file just as expected. The `<a>` inside the template allows me to click the profile and launch the modal. When clicked, the page darkens and scrolling is disabled except no modal window appears at all. When I view source, the modal is there in the HTML and has all the proper classes etc. I'll edit the question to show full HTML and JS.